# Add a new column with the names of columns where the row is True or some other specific value

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this data frame:

```
Name    Pr  VP  Tr  Me  Sa  Ar
Alicia  1   0   0   0   1   0
Bonnie  0   1   1   0   0   0
Cathy   1   1   1   1   1   1
Daphne  1   0   0   0   0   1
Elena   0   0   0   1   1   1
Faye    0   0   0   0   0   1
```

And I want to make this dataframe, which adds a column with the name of every column which is 1 in each row:

```
Name    Pr  VP  Tr  Me  Sa  Ar  Nominations
Alicia  1   0   0   0   1   0   Pr, Ar
Bonnie  0   1   1   0   0   0   VP, Tr
Cathy   1   1   1   1   1   1   Pr, VP, Tr, Me, Sa, Ar
Daphne  1   0   0   0   0   1   Pr, Ar
Elena   0   0   0   1   1   1   Me, Sa, Ar
Faye    0   0   0   0   0   1   Ar
```

I'd prefer tidyverse but base R would be useful to know too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can loop over the rows with `apply` and `MARGIN = 1` and `paste` the 'names' where the 'x' is 1

```
df1$Nominations <- apply(df1[-1], 1, function(x) toString(names(x)[x == 1]))
df1$Nominations
#[1] "Pr, Sa"                 "VP, Tr"                 "Pr, VP, Tr, Me, Sa, Ar" "Pr, Ar"                
#[5] "Me, Sa, Ar"             "Ar"
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`, reshape to 'long' format with `pivot_longer`, grouped by 'Name' `summarise` by `paste`ing the 'name' where the 'value' is 1 and join with the original dataset

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = -Name) %>% 
   group_by(Name) %>% 
   summarise(Nominations = toString(name[as.logical(value)])) %>% 
   right_join(df1) %>%
   select(names(df1), everything())
# A tibble: 6 x 8
#  Name      Pr    VP    Tr    Me    Sa    Ar Nominations           
#  <chr>  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <chr>                 
#1 Alicia     1     0     0     0     1     0 Pr, Sa                
#2 Bonnie     0     1     1     0     0     0 VP, Tr                
#3 Cathy      1     1     1     1     1     1 Pr, VP, Tr, Me, Sa, Ar
#4 Daphne     1     0     0     0     0     1 Pr, Ar                
#5 Elena      0     0     0     1     1     1 Me, Sa, Ar            
#6 Faye       0     0     0     0     0     1 Ar
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Name = c("Alicia", "Bonnie", "Cathy", "Daphne", 
"Elena", "Faye"), Pr = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), VP = c(0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Tr = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Me = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), Sa = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), Ar = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Making my own data for the example, and using the data.table package:

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(
  "name" = LETTERS[1:5],
  "V1" = c(1,0,0,1,0),
  "V2" = c(1,0,1,0,1))

dt1[melt(dt1, id.vars = "name")[value == 1, .(.(variable)), keyby = name], on = "name"]
```

---

Using data from Akrun

```
df1[melt(df1, id.vars = "Name")[value == 1, .(.(variable)), keyby = Name], on = "Name"]
```

Giving

```
     Name Pr VP Tr Me Sa Ar                V1
1: Alicia  1  0  0  0  1  0             Pr,Sa
2: Bonnie  0  1  1  0  0  0             VP,Tr
3:  Cathy  1  1  1  1  1  1 Pr,VP,Tr,Me,Sa,Ar
4: Daphne  1  0  0  0  0  1             Pr,Ar
5:  Elena  0  0  0  1  1  1          Me,Sa,Ar
6:   Faye  0  0  0  0  0  1                Ar
```

It's making a long data.table using name as the id, subsetting to those where there is a 1, and listing values that were the original column names (variable), then joining back to the original.